# How to use SendMessage to pass values from child dialog box(modeless) to parent dialog box?

Tags: mfc

Suppose I opened a popup from parent window I have calculated some calculation on child window while submitting the value from child window I need to display the calculated value of child window to parent window textbox when I click a button in the pop up window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

You can pass the parent window handle to your child window in the constructor and use it to call SendMessage. However since Send Message is a blocking call you can consider using Post Message Instead.

Option 2:

```
void CModeLess::OnOK() 
{
      //Get the value from the control
       m_ctrlEdit.GetWindowText(strVal);
       m_Parent->SetName(strVal);
       DestroyWindow(); 
}
```

Pass the parent dialog pointer while constructing the child dialog. And use it to call your member function.

Warning:

When you close the child window you should make sure to delete the memory of the child window pointer since you have mentioned the dialog is a modless. You need to inform the parent dialog that the child window is gone for that you need to use postmessage.

```
void CModeLess::PostNcDestroy() 
{   
    CDialog::PostNcDestroy();
    GetParent()->PostMessage(WM_MODELESS_CLOSED,0,0);
    delete this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your child window is associated with a class.

Add a method to the child window's class that will return the calculated value.  i.e. ChildwindowClass::GetCalculatedValue()

Then your parent window can use that method to get the value.

<strike>I'm assuming that you're using CDialog::DoModal to show the child window.  Since DoModal is a blocking function, it's easy to know when the child window is done.</strike>

Use PostMessage to inform the parent dialog that the child dialog is done its calculation and that GetCalculatedValue can be used.  Or you can pass the calculated value to the parent in PostMessage.

If the calculation is going to take a long time, use a worker thread to do it and PostMessage the result, otherwise you'll freeze your UI.

Comment: I didn't use DoModal to show the child dialog as it is a modeless dialog. And I have to use SendMessage/PostMessage to pass the values from child to parent.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that it was modeless.  Yup, that will work swell.  If the data is complex enough, you can use PostMesage() to inform the parent that the child is done, then have the parent use an accesor function to get the results of the calculation and cleanup the child dialog